# Using TS with Material UI and Styled Components

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I'm having trouble with this component where `checked` is throwing the following error:

```
`No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: CheckboxProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | Component<CheckboxProps, any, any> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'Boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
      Type 'Boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<CheckboxProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | Component<CheckboxProps, any, any> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'Boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
      Type 'Boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.`
```

```
<CheckboxDiv>
        <Checkbox
          onChange={() => dispatch(switchCompleted())}
          checked={status.showCompleted}
          style={{
            color: "#262626",
          }}
          classes={{ root: "custom-checkbox-root" }}
        />
 </CheckboxDiv>
```

and I don't know if it changes something, but I also have defined the size of the checkbox on the `index.html` file. It looks like this:

```
<style>
      .custom-checkbox-root .MuiSvgIcon-root {
        width: 2.1rem;
        height: 2.1rem;
      }
</style>
```